# Labeling columns in grouped charts separately

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts

I want to label sequentially some charts. Say, for instance, that I had:

```
BarChart[{{1, 3, 4}, {4, 5}}, ChartLabels -> {{"r1", "r2"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3","c4","c5"}}]
```

[image]

And I want to maintain those groups "r1" and "r2", but I want the columns to go from "c1" to "c5" without restarting. How can I do this?

Alternatively, I could change the coloring of the charts such that each group "r1" and "r2" had a distinct color from eachother (with a label on the right), but I would still have restarting labels "c1", "c2" and "c3".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function to label the data using `Labeled` as in @David's answer:

```
lblngF = MapIndexed[Function[{d, p},Labeled[d, #2[[1]][[## & @@ p]]]], #, {#2[[2]]}] &;
lblF = Fold[lblngF, #, Thread[{Reverse@#2, {2, 1}}]] &;

dt = {{1, 3, 4}, {4, 5}};
labels = {{"r1", "r2"}, {{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {"c4", "c5"}}};

BarChart[lblF[dt, labels]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can use the option `LabelingFunction`:

```
BarChart[dt, ChartLabels -> {{"\nr1", "\nr2"}, None}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[labels[[2]][[##]] & @@ #2, Below] &)]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: I'm taking this as the main answer because I feel like the labeling function is a bit more open to different datasets than David's. Still, both accomplish the result perfectly and I would select both answers if I could.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

```
BarChart[{
{Labeled[1,"c1"],Labeled[3,"c2"],Labeled[4,"c3"]},{Labeled[4,"c4"], Labeled[5,"c5"]}}, 
ChartLabels -> {{"r1","r2"},None}
]
```

[image]